# Android Systrace Trace File Format

Tags: android, linux, perf, ftrace, systrace

Android **systrace** tool, calls **atrace** tool via ADB. However, I don't understand very well the format of the traces file. Apparently it is very similar to linux **ftrace** tool with some differences. The main difference is that is doesn't uses a **System.Map** file but it includes all that information into the trace file. Also, there are new B|E entries that are android specific.

There is some information about this format in Android Source Code at: http://androidxref.com/4.1.1/xref/external/chromium-trace/src/tracing/linux_perf_importer.js

However, in that documentation we can read that the format belongs to Linux **Perf** Tool. I don't think so, linux perf gives as an output a very different format... (unless some special configuration is active...)

My question is: Does anybody know where can I found an official documentation about android trace files generated with **atrace** tool from adb?

Is this format familiar to you ?

```
# tracer: nop
#
# entries-in-buffer/entries-written: 66427/66427   #P:2
#
#                              _-----=> irqs-off
#                             / _----=> need-resched
#                            | / _---=> hardirq/softirq
#                            || / _--=> preempt-depth
#                            ||| /     delay
#           TASK-PID   CPU#  ||||    TIMESTAMP  FUNCTION
#              | |       |   ||||       |         |
          atrace-1724  [000] d..3 14186.680000: sched_switch: prev_comm=atrace prev_pid=1724 prev_prio=120 prev_state=S ==> next_comm=swapper/0 next_pid=0 next_prio=120
          <idle>-0     [000] d.h7 14186.690000: sched_wakeup: comm=tfm_b6bcf800 pid=1714 prio=35 success=1 target_cpu=000
          <idle>-0     [000] d..3 14186.690000: sched_switch: prev_comm=swapper/0 prev_pid=0 prev_prio=120 prev_state=R ==> next_comm=tfm_b6bcf800 next_pid=1714 next_prio=35
    tfm_b6bcf800-1714  [000] d..3 14186.690000: sched_switch: prev_comm=tfm_b6bcf800 prev_pid=1714 prev_prio=35 prev_state=D|W ==> next_comm=swapper/0 next_pid=0 next_prio=120
          <idle>-0     [001] d.h3 14186.690000: sched_wakeup: comm=Player Aud Mixe pid=146 prio=35 success=1 target_cpu=001
          <idle>-0     [001] d..3 14186.690000: sched_switch: prev_comm=swapper/1 prev_pid=0 prev_prio=120 prev_state=R ==> next_comm=Player Aud Mixe next_pid=146 next_prio=35
 Player Aud Mixe-146   [001] d..3 14186.690000: sched_switch: prev_comm=Player Aud Mixe prev_pid=146 prev_prio=35 prev_state=D ==> next_comm=swapper/1 next_pid=0 next_prio=120
          <idle>-0     [001] d.h3 14186.690000: sched_wakeup: comm=Player Aud Mixe pid=146 prio=35 success=1 target_cpu=001
          <idle>-0     [001] d..3 14186.690000: sched_switch: prev_comm=swapper/1 prev_pid=0 prev_prio=120 prev_state=R ==> next_comm=Player Aud Mixe next_pid=146 next_prio=35
 Player Aud Mixe-146   [001] d..3 14186.690000: sched_switch: prev_comm=Player Aud Mixe prev_pid=146 prev_prio=35 prev_state=S ==> next_comm=swapper/1 next_pid=0 next_prio=120
          <idle>-0     [001] d.h3 14186.700000: sched_wakeup: comm=Player Aud Mixe pid=146 prio=35 success=1 target_cpu=001
          <idle>-0     [001] d..3 14186.700000: sched_switch: prev_comm=swapper/1 prev_pid=0 prev_prio=120 prev_state=R ==> next_comm=Player Aud Mixe next_pid=146 next_prio=35
  EventThread-110   [001] d..5 14190.100000: sched_wakeup: comm=SurfaceFlinger pid=103 prio=112 success=1 target_cpu=001
     EventThread-110   [001] d..3 14190.100000: sched_switch: prev_comm=EventThread prev_pid=110 prev_prio=111 prev_state=S ==> next_comm=SurfaceFlinger next_pid=103 next_prio=112
  SurfaceFlinger-103   [001] ...1 14190.100000: tracing_mark_write: B|96|onMessageReceived
  SurfaceFlinger-103   [001] ...1 14190.100000: tracing_mark_write: B|96|handleTransaction
  SurfaceFlinger-103   [001] ...1 14190.100000: tracing_mark_write: B|96|doTransaction
  SurfaceFlinger-103   [001] ...1 14190.100000: tracing_mark_write: E
  SurfaceFlinger-103   [001] ...1 14190.100000: tracing_mark_write: E
  SurfaceFlinger-103   [001] ...1 14190.100000: tracing_mark_write: B|96|handleMessageInvalidate
  SurfaceFlinger-103   [001] ...1 14190.100000: tracing_mark_write: E
  SurfaceFlinger-103   [001] ...1 14190.100000: tracing_mark_write: E
  SurfaceFlinger-103   [001] ...1 14190.100000: tracing_mark_write: B|96|onMessageReceived
  SurfaceFlinger-103   [001] ...1 14190.100000: tracing_mark_write: B|96|handleMessageRefresh
  SurfaceFlinger-103   [001] ...1 14190.100000: tracing_mark_write: B|96|rebuildLayerStacks
  SurfaceFlinger-103   [001] ...1 14190.100000: tracing_mark_write: B|96|computeVisibleRegions
  SurfaceFlinger-103   [001] ...1 14190.100000: tracing_mark_write: E
  SurfaceFlinger-103   [001] ...1 14190.100000: tracing_mark_write: E
  SurfaceFlinger-103   [001] ...1 14190.100000: tracing_mark_write: B|96|doComposition
  SurfaceFlinger-103   [001] d.h4 14190.100000: sched_wakeup: comm=surfaceflinger pid=96 prio=120 success=1 target_cpu=001
  SurfaceFlinger-103   [001] d..3 14190.100000: sched_switch: prev_comm=SurfaceFlinger prev_pid=103 prev_prio=112 prev_state=R ==> next_comm=surfaceflinger next_pid=96 next_prio=120
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Maybe not exactly what you are looking for, but helpful?: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/systrace.html

Comment: Which command did you use to generate the above log? I could not find the command to generate the lines containing "tracing_mark_write: B|" and "tracing_mark_write: E"

Comment: _atrace_ command is a "hidden" command in Android shell console (adb). It is generally invoked by _systrace_ python script. I've obtainded this log by manually executing _atrace_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, now it is sure: the format belongs to **ftrace** tool. Android **atrace** is an extension of **ftrace** build to facilitate configuration.

The official documentation from **ftrace**, shows that this output format can directly be produced by it in the following way:

```
root@adroid:# echo 1 > /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/sched/sched_switch/enable
root@adroid:# echo 1 > /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/tracing_on
root@adroid:# cat /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace > mytracefile.txt
root@adroid:# echo 0 > /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/tracing_on
root@adroid:# echo 0 > /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/sched/sched_switch/enable
```

Official Documentation at:
http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/trace/ftrace.txt

```
# cat trace
# tracer: nop
#
# entries-in-buffer/entries-written: 77/77   #P:8
#
#                              _-----=> irqs-off
#                             / _----=> need-resched
#                            | / _---=> hardirq/softirq
#                            || / _--=> preempt-depth
#                            ||| /     delay
#           TASK-PID   CPU#  ||||    TIMESTAMP  FUNCTION
#              | |       |   ||||       |         |
          <idle>-0     [007] d...  2440.707395: sched_switch: prev_comm=swapper/7 prev_pid=0 prev_prio=120 prev_state=R ==> next_comm=snapshot-test-2 next_pid=2243 next_prio=120
 snapshot-test-2-2229  [002] d...  2440.707438: sched_switch: prev_comm=snapshot-test-2 prev_pid=2229 prev_prio=120 prev_state=S ==> next_comm=swapper/2 next_pid=0 next_prio=120
[...]
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Great post however don't forget to MOUNT the debug filesystem,

```
"mount -t debugfs none /sys/kernel/debug" or 
"mount -o rw,remount -t debugfs none /sys/kernel/debug"
```

otherwise you will not get something like

> "error opening /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/options/overwrite: No such
>   file or directory "

when running atrace

Some more usefull info here http://rahulonblog.blogspot.se/2013/06/how-to-enable-debugfs-in-kernel.html